# Excel/VBA - Extracting a range of rows from a selected sheet to a new book

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to build a new VBA function for Excel. I've got a book of sheets with a front page that always loads first, on this page I've got a combo box that lists all the other sheets in the book and a nice extract button that will pull out the chosen sheet to a new book. (Thanks to those here who helped with that). Now I need a new function that will use the same combo box, but instead only extract a small subset of the chosen sheet.

Unfortunately, that subset isn't on the same rows for every sheet, nor is the number of rows the same (so one sheet, the subset might be 10 rows, on another it might be 12, on another it might be 20, etc etc etc).

On the plus side, there are merged rows (from column A to G) at the start and end of each subset - with specific text, which could be used to search for.

After some back and forth, I've got a better bit of code that I think is almost working:

```
Sub ZCPS_Extract()

Dim StartRow
Dim EndRow

Dim Zws As Worksheet

Dim wbkOriginal As Workbook
Set wbkOriginal = ActiveWorkbook

StartRow = 1
EndRow = 1

'sets site details into the header of the ZCPS checksheet
Worksheets(Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value).Range("B3").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("E6")
Worksheets(Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value).Range("D3").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("N6")
Worksheets(Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value).Range("F3").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("K6")

Set Zws = Sheets(Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value)

'selects ZCPS block from select estate sheet
StartRow = (Zws.Cells.Find("**** ZCPS Installation").Row) + 1
EndRow = (Zws.Cells.Find("**** Aztec Hotfixes").Row) - 1

'copy above block and paste into Z-MISC starting at row 5
Worksheets(Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value).Range(Cells(StartRow, 1), Cells(EndRow, 7)).Copy Worksheets("Z-MISC").Range("A5")

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Z-MISC")
            .Copy
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
            "C:\temp\" _
            & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Z-MISC").Cells(3, 2).Text _
            & " ZCPS CheckSheet " _
            & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YY") _
            & ".xlsm", _
            xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, , , , False
        End With

'code to close the original workbook to prevent accidental changes etc
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wbkOriginal.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

It's error on the line for copying, I'm getting a runtime error of "Application-defined or object-defined error" which to my limited knowledge isn't helping me. Any assistance/pointers/suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Do some more trying. Come back when you encounter real problems.

Comment: Changed the copy line which has got me a little further, now reading as: `Worksheets(Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value).Range(Cells(StartRow, 1), Cells(EndRow, 7)).Copy _
    Destination:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Z-MISC").Range("A10")` - still getting an object reference error though, and I can't see why. Object watchers on the variables give me information that matches up with what I'd expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working.

```
    Set Zws = Sheets(Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value)


'selects ZCPS block from selected estate sheet
StartRow = (Zws.Cells.Find("**** ZCPS Installation").Row)
EndRow = (Zws.Cells.Find("**** Aztec Hotfixes").Row) - 1

'copy above block and paste into Z-MISC starting at row 10

Sheets(Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(StartRow, 1), Cells(EndRow, 7)).Select

    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Z-MISC").Select
    Range("A10").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ismerged()
Dim start As Integer, finish As Integer
For i = 1 To Range("A655").End(3).Row + 1
    If Cells(i, "A").MergeCells = True Then
        start = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next

For i = start To Range("A655").End(3).Row + 1
    If Cells(i, "A").MergeCells = True Then
        finish = i
    End If
Next
MsgBox start
MsgBox finish


End Sub
```

Then I guess you can select your data as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the way you reference your sheet. I will assume 'comboboxvalue' contains the name or the number of the sheet you are selecting. Your code should be something like the following.

```
Sub Z_Extract()
Dim StartRow
Dim EndRow
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets(comboboxvalue)
StartRow = ws.Cells.Find("**** ZC").Row
EndRow = ws.Cells.Find("****").Row

'Im assuming you have values up to column G
ws.Range(ws.Cells(StartRow, 1), Cells(EndRow, 7)).Copy

'Now that you have the correct Range selected you can copy it to your new workbook

'SelectedRange.Copy Etc.....

'Cleanup

Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```